# Why it is not showing error, when using const in useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my complete React js code. I am using const in "const [name, setName] =useState('Micheal');". It is not showing error, when I am changing name using setName function. Since const in javascript means, it cannot be unchanged, why it is not showing any error

```
import React,{useState} from "react"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
function Emp(){
  const [name,setName]=useState("Micheal");
  const [id,setId]=useState(1024);
  const [age,setAge]=useState(23);
  const handleClick=()=>{
    setName("Jackson");
    setId(2021);
    setAge(29);
  }
  return (
    <>
    <h1>Emp Details</h1>
    <h1>your name: {name}</h1>
    <h1>your id: {id}</h1>
    <h1>your age: {age}</h1>
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Click Here</button>
    </>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Emp/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Cause `Emp` is called multiple times, and each time the variables can hold different values. They just cannot be changed "inside one function call"

Comment: @JonasWilms but we are calling Emp component only once in ReactDOM.render

Comment: No. `<Emp/>` is not a call. It hands over the function (and the props) to the React library, and that can call it as often as it wants to.

Comment: that's not really what `const` means. it's to prevent you from reassigning the actual variables like `const x = 3; x = 4`; <-- which will throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `const` means that the identifier can’t be reassigned. (Not to be confused with immutable values. Unlike true immutable datatypes such as those produced by Immutable.js and Mori, a `const` object can have properties mutated.)

From: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

For example:

```js
const obj1 = {};
obj1.a = '12345'

console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example from the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#recap

Specifically, this line:
 `Line 9: When the user clicks, we call setCount with a new value. React will then re-render the Example component, passing the new count value to it.`

Every time you call setId, for example, useState will return a new value for id, and re-render your component. It is not simply assigning a variable - useState has side effects, and does more than just assign a value.

This is not in violation of the use of `const`, because useState is technically returning a newly initialized value and re-rendering with that value. It is not double assigning, renaming or anything like that.

Lastly, `const` also prevents you from mistakenly re-assigning the useState variables within your component.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. That *re-render* part mean React isn't reassigning, so const will remain constant as long as the state isn't changed by the set method.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is API hook of React that we call it this way: `const [name, setName] =useState('Micheal');`

and this is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment, name is a constant referencing to object behind state called `Micheal` by you and `setName` is a function to notice to React state that the `Micheal` will have change and the `Micheal` will have new value after that, this way the whole component will rerender again...